# MySQL search for value containing spaces returns empty result (no rows)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `MySQL` **database** with a column containing **part numbers**. Some of the part numbers contain **spaces**:

```
3864205010  J
```

When I query the database or **search** for the part in `phpMyAdmin` no results are returned.

Yet when I `delete` the **2 spaces** and then *type* them again, the search returns a result.

This query does not return a result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `parts` 
WHERE  `part_no` LIKE  '3864205010  K'
```

This query returns the result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `parts` 
WHERE  `part_no` LIKE  '3864205010  K'
```

They look the same but in the second query I have deleted the 2 spaces before "K" and typed the spaces again.

Comment: not clear enough buddy

Comment: Your data type is varchar or text ? Show us your query

Comment: Unfortunately as a new member I can't add images to support my question.

Comment: You can copy paste it in. Then CTRL+K to format nicely

Comment: Actually just paste it in... someone else (even me) will format it for you if you have no idea.

Comment: I receive an error message saying I need reputation of 10 to post images.

Comment: copy and paste the raw text code (when in edit mode of your question)

Comment: Did you not type the first query? - with spaces i.e.?

Comment: this is probably not a space but a HTAB (ascii code 9) or even a line feed/carriage return (10 and 13). Copy paste in a good text editor, you'll see

Comment: Why you use LIKE for search exact result?

Comment: Yeah Sebas is right. It seems like you have some other character than renders like a 'space' there but is indeed something else.

Comment: Sebas, I will try your advise. Narek, I have used LIKE in this example but in my website query I search for exact values. Both methods result in the same issue.

Comment: @Sebas, you were indeed correct. The first space was a "real" space, the second was not. What I don't understand is if the part is saved in the database with 1 space and 1 other character that looks like a space, why searching for this value returns no result. However a search for the part with 2 real spaces does return a result. Strange. Anyway, how can I accept your answer if its places as a comment, I'm a new member, did not work out all the rules here yet...

Comment: I'll make an answer with additional information then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not a space but a HTAB (ascii code 9) or even a line feed/carriage return (10 and 13). Copy paste in a good text editor, you'll see what it really is.

Now, regarding to your wonder about why it doesn't work even if it does *look like* a space, this is because every single character we *see* is interpreted by the engine (notepad, phpmyadmin, firefox... any software with text rendering)

What actually happens is that when the engine finds an ascii code, it transforms it into a visible character. The CHAR(9) for example is often transformed into a 'big space' usually equal to 2 or 4 spaces. But phpmyadmin might just decide to not do it that way.

Other example is the line feed (CHAR(10)). In a text editor it would be the signal that the line ends, and (under unix systems mostly) a new line has to start. But you can copy this line feed into a database field, you're just not sure about how it is going to render. 
Because they want you to see everything in the cell they may choose to render it as a space... but that's NOT a space if you look at the ascii code of it (and here there's no trick, all rendering engines will tell you the right ascii code).

This is important to always treat characters with their ascii codes.

---

there's an answer above that suggests using a wildcard instead of the spaces. That might match, or just might not. Let's say your string is '386420K5010', so it is not the one you're looking for, still the LIKE  '3864205010%K' pattern would return it. The best is probably to use a regular expression or at least identify the fixed pattern of these strings.

Comment: ill probably clean up the data in my data database, just replace all <space><non-space> with <space><space>

Answer (score 2):

If you can use wildcard instead of spaces:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `parts` 
WHERE  `part_no` LIKE  '3864205010%K'
```

Comment: If I could give more than +1 I would. spot on buddy

Answer (score 0):

yes as updated question if you wish to remove more space between which contents might be 3 or 4 space below query will use full to you

```
SELECT REPLACE( REPLACE( part_no, " ", " " ), " ", " " ) from parts.
```

let me know if it is work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `parts` 
WHERE  REPLACE(REPLACE(`part_no`, CHAR(9), ''),' ','') LIKE  REPLACE(REPLACE('3864205010  K', CHAR(9), ''),' ','')
```

This will probably work if `part_no` and/or search string has tabs and/or spaces.